# node app deployed in azure app service, No webpage was found for the web address:

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a node app into azure app service, but when i browse the website it's showing

[image: here]

but when i'm running it locally it's showing success message in postman

[image: here]

and when i check through the url in postman it's showing same 404 error

[image: here]

i have deployed the code to app service using azure appservice extension in vscode and the output terminal is showing deployment successful

[image: here]

and to double check i have used kudo tools and the wwwroot folder showing everything as expected

[image: here]

i'm not able to find the solution, where i'm going wrong?